# Can Acer Aspire S7 Ultrabook play/display 3D movies?

Tags: acer-aspire, intel-graphics, 3d

I have an Acer Aspire S7 Ultrabook and an Aaxa LED 3D Pico projector, both connected through HDMI cable which supports 3D. The projector information does mention 3D movies but, while playing 3D media (with Windows Media Player) on the laptop, it shows as side by side image and same while projecting.

Any input at to whether the laptop supports 3D will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware seems to support it, since all S7 use Ivy Bridge CPUs with an iGPU supporting Intel InTru 3D (HDMI 1.4 3D). You probably need a special player like CyberLink; the latest Intel graphics drivers; and 3D glasses compatible with the 3D method of your projector. If you have an Nvidia card in there as well, there could be complications due to the Optimus tech and having both the Intel and Nvidia graphics stacks installed, so you may have to force your media playing application to run on the Intel chip (or the Nvidia chip if you already tried that). But you didn't specify which exact model of the S7 you have, so I have no idea what kind of hardware you actually have; there are tons of different models of the S7 with different capabilities.

Also make sure you have stereoscopic enabled in the control panel under display.

Comment: The model no. is S7-391-9427

Comment: It *should* work. That CPU supports InTru 3D. You need to purchase a media player software that supports InTru 3D. At this point it seems like you have all the hardware you need to do this, so the problems that remain are purely software. I could be wrong though.

Comment: If you appreciate my inputs, please consider accepting this as the answer to the question, and/or upvoting.